# How to create a mixed model with count data and random effects in R for complex ecological data?

Tags: r, mixed-model, count-data, ecology

I have a question about performing a mixed effects model with random effects in R. I want to test whether there are differences in symbiont genus between coral genera from 4 different types of reef habitat.

Due to host specificity there is an interaction with coral genus. Basically I want to see if there is a difference in symbiont genus between the four habitats (but add coral_genus in the model as well due to host specificity), which is the reason I thought it's best to include Coral_genus as a random factor in the model. So symbiont_genus is sort of the response variable, however because this is a categorical variable, I thought to use Sample_size (count data; numerical) as the response variable and Symbiont_genus in the model as an explanatory variable, because I want to perform a mixed effects model using the lme4 package in R I have to use a numerical response variable.

I have a dataset with Sample_size (numerical; integers), Symbiont_genus (factor with 3 levels), Habitat (factor with 4 levels) and Coral_genus (factor with 12 levels):

Subset of dataset looks like this (*see below*). If I use Sample_size as a response variable like so:

```r
sym_mixed = lmer(Sample_size ~ Habitat + (1 | Coral_genus), 
    data = extremes)
```

It is not clear that I want to test for differences in Symbiont_genus.

However, incorporating that in the model, I'm not sure how to interpret the outcome.

```r
sym_mixed = lmer(Sample_size ~ Symbiont_genus + Habitat + 
    (1 | Coral_genus), data = extremes)
```

Since I have count data, I might need to use a mixed model with Poisson distribution, however I thought this is often used with zero-inflated data when the response is an integer and often contains many zeroes. My dataset does not contain zeros because if the symbiont genus was not found somewhere for a particular coral genus, it was not reported. Would it still be appropriate in this case to continue with the “glmer” with Poisson distribution or if this is no longer appropriate due to absence of many zeros in the dataset?

So the model would be:

```r
sym_mixed = glmer(Sample_size ~ Symbiont_genus + Habitat + 
    (1 | Coral_genus), family=“Poisson”, data = extremes)
```

However, I struggle to interpret the outcome of such a model. Does anyone have suggestions on how to perform a statistical analysis on this kind of data and how to interpret the outcome?

**An example (small subset of dataset) looks like this:**

[image: Subset of data]